# Custom Menu Items in AVPlayerViewController

Tags: tvos, avplayerviewcontroller, avkit

On tvOS, is it possible to add custom items to the `AVPlayerViewController` Info/Subtitles/Audio menu? Not just adding metadata items, but a whole new section. I'd like to provide an additional menu item after Subtitles for playback speed selection with selectable options like 1.0x, 2.0x, etc.

If this is not possible with `AVPlayerViewController`, is it possible using a custom view with an embedded `AVPlayer` like it is on iOS?